# How do I send Apple Pay Payment Token to Stripe to complete the charge?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, stripe-payments

I am using swiftUI. My code currently is using PassKit alone. It integrates with swiftUI nicely and I am able to get the payment.token encrypted from apple pay. I want to use that token, and tokenized it client-side (according to stripe docs, this is the best way to stay compliant with laws) and send it to stripe to complete the payment. I am having issue as to what API endpoints to call in order to send and complete all this while staying compliant. The docs only show using Stripe SDK which is very hard to integrate with swiftui.

```
import PassKit
import Stripe


typealias PaymentCompletionHandler = (Bool) -> Void

class PaymentHandler: NSObject{

static let supportedNetworks: [PKPaymentNetwork] = [
    .amex,
    .masterCard,
    .visa
]

var paymentController: PKPaymentAuthorizationController?
var paymentSummaryItems = [PKPaymentSummaryItem]()
var paymentStatus = PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus.failure
var completionHandler: PaymentCompletionHandler?

    func startPayment(client: ClientData, completion: @escaping PaymentCompletionHandler) {
        let cartTotal = client.cart.totalPrice
        let salesTax = client.cart.tax

        let amount = PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Amount", amount: NSDecimalNumber(value: cartTotal), type: .final)
        let tax = PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Tax", amount: NSDecimalNumber(value: salesTax), type: .final)
        let total = PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "ToTal", amount: NSDecimalNumber(value: cartTotal + salesTax), type: .final)

    paymentSummaryItems = [amount, tax, total];
    completionHandler = completion

    // Create our payment request
    let paymentRequest = PKPaymentRequest()
    paymentRequest.paymentSummaryItems = paymentSummaryItems
    paymentRequest.merchantIdentifier = "merchant.com.xxxxx"
    paymentRequest.merchantCapabilities = .capability3DS
    paymentRequest.countryCode = "US"
    paymentRequest.currencyCode = "USD"
//    .phoneNumber, .emailAddress, .postalAddress
    paymentRequest.requiredShippingContactFields = []
    paymentRequest.supportedNetworks = PaymentHandler.supportedNetworks

    // Display our payment request
    paymentController = PKPaymentAuthorizationController(paymentRequest: paymentRequest)
    paymentController?.delegate = self
    paymentController?.present(completion: { (presented: Bool) in
        if presented {
            NSLog("Presented payment controller")
        } else {
            NSLog("Failed to present payment controller")
            self.completionHandler!(false)
         }
     })
  }
}

/*
    PKPaymentAuthorizationControllerDelegate conformance.
*/
extension PaymentHandler: PKPaymentAuthorizationControllerDelegate{
   
    

func paymentAuthorizationController(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationController, didAuthorizePayment payment: PKPayment, completion: @escaping (PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus) -> Void) {

//    // Perform some very basic validation on the provided contact information
//    if payment.shippingContact?.emailAddress == nil || payment.shippingContact?.phoneNumber == nil {
//        paymentStatus = .failure
//    } else {
//        // Here you would send the payment token to your server or payment provider to process
//        // Once processed, return an appropriate status in the completion handler (success, failure, etc)
//        paymentStatus = .success
//    }
    let data = payment.token.paymentData
    let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any]

    print(json)
    paymentStatus = .success
    completion(paymentStatus)
}

func paymentAuthorizationControllerDidFinish(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationController) {
    controller.dismiss {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if self.paymentStatus == .success {
                print()
                self.completionHandler!(true)
            } else {
                self.completionHandler!(false)
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

I am thinking of sending the token/ tokenizing it in the paymentAuthorizationControllerDidFinish() function on .success and let stripe finish the charge.

Currently I think the steps are:

1. Create a new stripe customer on backend when apple Pay is tapped -> send id back to client.
2. Create a payment intent -> send id back to client.

3...? I am lost here on sending stripe all of the above along with the payment source, in my case is an encrypted payment token by apple.

i have tried sending a request to https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges? api and sending the entire token, but it says invalid request. I know its brute forcing but i am desperate :/

**UPDATE 2**

I used

```
    STPAPIClient.shared().createPaymentMethod(with: payment) { (source, err) in
        
        
        if let err = err {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            self.paymentStatus = .failure
            completion(self.paymentStatus)
        }
        // returns a hashable [dictionary]
      
        guard let sourceDetails = source?.allResponseFields else
        {
            self.paymentStatus = .failure
            return
        }
        print(sourceDetails)
    

            AF.request("http://localhost:5001/rxxxxx/us-central1/paymentIntent", method: .post, parameters: ["data" : sourceDetails]).response { (response) in
                if let data = response.data {
                    guard let res = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {return}
                    print(res)
                } else {
                    print("almo fire err")
                }


            }
```

And my backend returns a success response from Stripe
[DELETED]

```
However, nothing has been charged or created in my Stripe dashboard.


**UPDATE 3**

I was able to confirm the payment intent using postman and calling the API and passing in the PayMent Method id directly. Still trying to implement using typescript.


LAST QUESTION. Is this PCI compliance? I have zero idea how all this is working. No client is created in dashboard, is this even working? The charges are being posted though. I am just confused because everything that i passed around didn't even show a full card number....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't using the Stripe iOS SDK, try passing the PKPayment's properties to the /v1/tokens endpoint on Stripe in the parameters shown here: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/a05b307c8a9ef6ee6c53726da2392073b5292f19/Stripe/STPAPIClient%2BApplePay.swift#L156-L189 and

That gives you back a Token object. Create a PaymentMethod object using that Token object (as Tokens are legacy) with the /v1/payment_methods endpoint and passing `card: {token: tok_visa }`, which gets you back a PaymentMethod object: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create#create_payment_method-card

Now you can attach the PaymentMethod to a PaymentIntent and confirm it server-side.

Comment: hi sorry i am very noob. I do have the sdk, but can't follow the normal tutorial because of swiftui. So I pass the payload to one of these API: https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens ? It doesn't return anything that I can use to fill the payment_methods API such as credit card details. I tried using createTokenWithPayment from the stripe sdk but cannot enocde it to json to send to my server and fill in the CreateCharge API.

Comment: Am I on the right path trying to use STPAPIClient.shared().createSource and passing it to createCharges in my server? is the token created by the sdk method a valid parameter for the createCharges parameter called sources?

Comment: hello. i posted another update. please take a look. @hmunoz

Comment: ok so it looks like you have a PaymentIntent and a Token. You need to send that Token to your backend to confirm the PaymentIntent on your server.

Comment: actually it looks like you do not have a Token object. I would encourage that you just use the STPAPIClient.shared.createTokenWithPayment() method on the iOS app to obtain a Token from Stripe, in exchange of the Apple Pay token

Comment: "but cannot enocde it to json to send to my server and fill in the CreateCharge API"
You would have to figure out how to send data from your client to the server and then parse out the token on your server-side endpoint, there are tutorials online that can help with that depending on your language and framework on how to encode and pass JSON data in HTTP requests

Comment: I did not use the token, instead i used the createPaymentMethod using the Stripe sdk, -> pass in the paymentMethod id to the sever to create an intent then -> gets the id from response -> then confirming the intent by passing the id into another method on the server. Here is an image: https://imgur.com/a/qX1ESSX it looks like its working... like you said i did not use the createToken way, why is it working? is this bad?

Comment: is it bad that I did not use createToken? I used createPaymentMethod and passed in the method ID to paymentIntents as payment source...

Comment: Creating a PaymentMethod object (vs the legacy Token) is fine and rather, recommended (also using PaymentIntents, over the legacy Charges).